# delete from database error after expiration

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

In my database I have many products that have a datecreated attribute. 
I want to delete any product after an amount of time, like 10 or 20 days, when I refresh my home page.

This is my controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $datenow = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    $datenowStringType = $datenow->format('Y-m-d');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $products = $em->getRepository('ProductBundle:Product')->findAll();

    foreach ($products as $produit) {
        $CreatedDate = $produit->getCreatedDate();
        $CreatedDate_StringType = $CreatedDate->format('Y-m-d');

        $duree = '+'.$produit->getDuree();
        $date_fin_duree = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($CreatedDate_StringType.$duree));

        if ( strtotime($datenowStringType)<strtotime($date_fin_duree) ) {
             $em->remove($produit);
        }
    }
    array_values($products);

    return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', array(
        'products' => $products,
    ));
}
```

There are no errors returned, but the product isn't deleted. It could be a simple error but I searched a lot and I think it's a lack of concentration.
Please help?

Comment: Where are you calling flush ?

Comment: i called it after i remove but he delete the product even the condition is false

Comment: thanks Rhono do you have any solution ?

Comment: As Cerad said, `$em->flush();` before `return $this->render(...` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = ''; // calculate your date here, it should be DateTime object
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->delete('Product', 'p');
$qb->where('p.duree < :date');
$qb->setParameter('date', $date);
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.